# Problems with multicasts in "iptables"

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall, multicast

My question is related to multicasts and `iptables`.

I want to allow ICMP and IGMP multicasts from the local VLAN `192.168.1.0/24` as well as from `0.0.0.0` on my CentOS machine, so I added the following rules to my inbound chain:

```
# ACCEPT - Multicast 224.0.0.1 from current VLAN as well as 0.0.0.0
# -- ICMP
iptables -A IP-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 224.0.0.1 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast --protocol icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A IP-INPUT -s 0.0.0.0        -d 224.0.0.1 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast --protocol icmp -j ACCEPT
# -- IGMP
iptables -A IP-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 224.0.0.1 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast --protocol igmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A IP-INPUT -s 0.0.0.0        -d 224.0.0.1 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast --protocol igmp -j ACCEPT
```

I also ensured that the `xt_pkttype` kernel module is loaded.

But that does not seem to work ... I'm getting denies:

```
Oct 12 09:06:22 192.168.1.102 IPTABLES: :: IN::DENY    2          0.0.0.0       ==>        224.0.0.1
```

I noticed that the deny line shows the protocol number (`2`) instead of its name (`IGMP`), but that does not seem to matter. If I replace `--protocol igmp` in the rules with `--protocol 2` it's the same.

After some googling I also noticed some people do it this way, but it also does not work for me:

```
# ACCEPT - Multicast 224.0.0.1 from current VLAN as well as 0.0.0.0
iptables -A IP-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 224.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A IP-INPUT -s 0.0.0.0        -d 224.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

If relevant, I use `iptables` version `1.4.7` on CentOS `6.3` with kernel version `2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64`.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

- The requested content of `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` (see below)
- Changes to the rules suggested by Michael Hampton

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Jan 16 14:33:55 2013
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:IP-FORWARD - [0:0]
:IP-INPUT - [0:0]
:IP-OUTPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j IP-INPUT 
-A FORWARD -j IP-FORWARD 
-A OUTPUT -j IP-OUTPUT 
-A IP-FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "server-FORWARD: " 
-A IP-FORWARD -j DROP 
-A IP-INPUT -i lo -m comment --comment "ACCEPT all packets ON LOOPBACK" -j ACCEPT 
-A IP-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A IP-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 224.0.0.1/32 -p icmp -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT 
-A IP-INPUT -d 224.0.0.1/32 -p icmp -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT 
-A IP-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 224.0.0.1/32 -p igmp -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT 
-A IP-INPUT -d 224.0.0.1/32 -p igmp -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
-A IP-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IP-INPUT -p icmp -f -m comment --comment "DROP fragmented icmp" -j DROP 
-A IP-INPUT -p icmp -m comment --comment "ACCEPT incoming icmp" -j ACCEPT 
-A IP-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -m comment --comment "DROP packets with illegal flags" -j DROP 
-A IP-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP 
-A IP-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP 
-A IP-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP 
-A IP-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP 
-A IP-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j DROP 
-A IP-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP 
-A IP-INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j LOG 
-A IP-INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A IP-INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "server-INPUT: " 
-A IP-OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j LOG --log-prefix "server-OUTPUT: " 
-A IP-OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A IP-OUTPUT -o lo -m comment --comment "ACCEPT all packets ON LOOPBACK" -j ACCEPT 
-A IP-OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A IP-OUTPUT -p icmp -f -m comment --comment "DROP fragmented icmp" -j DROP 
-A IP-OUTPUT -p icmp -m comment --comment "ACCEPT outgoing icmp" -j ACCEPT 
-A IP-OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "server-OUTPUT: " 
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jan 16 14:33:55 2013
```

Comment: can you list the whole output from /etc/sysconfig/iptables? that might help answer this question.

Comment: Just added the requested output, see above.

Comment: What programs are you using to send/receive the multicast packets?

Comment: @Dave Johnson: Actually, I don't use any tools to send or receive those packages, these multicasts are sent by certain devices inside our network.

Comment: We still need to know if the packets are being sent and received properly. Can you see these packets with Wireshark to make sure they're being sent? And what sort of multicast packet is it? There has to be something listening for it to actually receive it.

Comment: @Dave Johnson: I can see these packages using Wireshark. Some of them are from routers and are described as a `60 V2 Membership Query, general`. So, it seems like they are being sent.

Comment: Ah, OK. That's IGMP traffic. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Yes, `IGMP` (sorry, that I did not mention that within my last post). I just want `iptables` to accept these packages instead of denying them.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to see IGMP packets unless you're running a router daemon.

Answer (score 1):

You added your rules AFTER the rules which LOG and DROP your traffic. Those rules should be the *last* rules in the table. Just rearrange the lines so that they appear last.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! So, I just rearranged the rules and reloaded the ruleset. The multicasts are still being denied.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your machine to respond to multicast ping, you have to run

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=0
```

By default, this ICMP broadcast/multicast is ignored, for obvious reasons.

Comment: We only need that on certain machines, not generally on every server. In most cases broadcasts and multicasts will be dropped. Thanks for the command. Even if `icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=0`, `IGMP` packets should be accepted with the rules mentioned above, shouldn't they?

Comment: IGMP is mostly to tell routers about joining multicast groups, so unless you're actually routing packets with this server, you don't need it. You can still send/receive multicast traffic without being able to receive IGMP.

Comment: I'm just wondering why `iptables` denies the packets, even though there are rules to accept it.